# The number of numbers not divisible by $2,3,5,7$ or $11$ between multiples of $2310$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Looking at partitions of the natural number line of the form $P=[a,b)$, I noted that

- if $a$ and $b$ are multiples of $6$, there exist at least $2$ numbers in the partition which are not divisible by $2$ or $3$
- if $a$ and $b$ are multiples of $30$, there exist $8$ numbers in the partition which are not divisible by $2, 3$ or $5$
- if $a$ and $b$ are multiples of $210$, there exist $54$ numbers in the partition which are not divisible by $2,3,5$ or $7$.

This leads me to guess that if $a$ and $b$ are multiples of $2310$, there exist $592$ numbers in the partition which are not divisible by $2,3,5,7$ or $11$. Is this true?

(I arrived at $592$ because it is equal to $54 \times 11 - 2$ and $2310$ because it is equal to $210 \times 11$.)

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Good work! I believe you will find that for $210$ it is $48$, not $54$. You are in the process of discovering the Euler $\varphi$ function.

Comment: @Andre Thank you! I noted that are 35 primes between 210 and 420 as well as 8 numbers whose lowest divisor is 11, 6 with ld=13, 3 with ld=17 and 2 with ld=19, hence the 54...?

Comment: You have done some "double-counting."

Comment: I'll double check cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use chinese remainder representation with basis $[2,3,5,7,11]$.

Given a CRR basis $[a,b,c,d,e]$ with $M = abcde = 2\times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 = 2310$, each valid tuple represents exactly 1 number from $0$ to $M - 1 \pmod M$.  So you want the number of tuples that don't contain a zero, or $(a - 1)(b - 1)(c - 1)(d - 1)(e - 1)$ or $1 \times 2 \times 4 \times 6 \times 10 = 480$.