# The sum of 2 positive integers is 2310. Show that their product is not divisible by 2310.

Tags: arithmetic

I'm not sure how to start. Is 2310 some special number?

Comment: Yes, it's a special number: 2310 =2*3*5*7*11

Comment: @J.G.: How would that work? The sum of two _positive_ multiples of $2310$ can't be $2310$.

Comment: Also $2310$ is a square-free number,I guess that makes it special.

Comment: @Henning I think J.G. meant two *divisors* of that number, e.g., 1155 + 1155. Although... their product, 1334025, is clearly odd.

Answer (score 0):

$$a + b = N$$

Let $N\mid a\cdot b$. If $p$ is some prime such that $p\mid N$, then both $a$ and $b$ are definitely divisible by $p$.

$2310$ is made up of $5$ different primes. So, if $N\mid a, b$, then both $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $N$. So, $N = a + b \ge 2N$. Contradition.

Comment: Can you explain to me what "N|a*b" means? I forgot...

Comment: @GerardL., it means that $a\cdot b = Nm$ for some integer $m$

Comment: If $a+b=2310=2*3*5*7*11$, then both $a,b$ are odd, even. Let, $a=2308=2*2*577, b=2; a=2307=3*769, b=3$. Get that both $577, 769$ are primes, although not concerned with the problem as if change $2310$ to $2312=2*1156=2*2*578=2*2*2*289$, still the same issue persists. To prove, their product $2310 \not | \,\,\, a*b$, need show there is different set of primes in each. Might be need a different approach as at:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/714294/424260